# TL-WN821N(v4) wont turn on (working on another installation)

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet

I've had dual boot with ubuntu(work)+mint(general).

The wireless card (TL-WN821N(v4)) used to work very well (not without issues, I had to receive [help](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=159484&p=823557#p823956) on linux mint forums)

Now I decided to put ubuntu instead of mint, and the card doesn't turn on.

I cant remember the steps to make it work,
So now I have two installation of ubuntu, one detects the card, the other doesn't.

I tried following the advice I mention above, without luck.

Please tell me the steps to figure out why the wireless card refuses to turn on.

Comment: Did the driver compile when you tried to install it or were there errors?

Comment: there were errors at this stage: "sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.8"

Comment: Try it like this `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.9` I believe that driver version changed.

Comment: @WildMan good eyes, I didn't notice the version change 0_o. Please write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I will in a few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver version changed you need to get the driver from [here](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes).

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

Clone this repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
```

Set it up as a DKMS

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
```

Build and install it:

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.9
```

Refresh module list:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Ensure the native kernel driver is blacklisted:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Directions are from [here](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes).

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. who ever is looking for a driver, this is the address with instructions: https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes